# How to display an image if variable equals a special number using swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have three pictures (`lvl1.png, lvl2.png, lvl3.png`) and an variable (`let level = 1`). What should I do to display an image named 'lvl2' if `level = 2`, and when `level = 3` I need to show the last image (lvl3.png)?

Comment: `imageview.image = UIImage(named: "lvl\(level)")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "lvl\(level).png")
```

or

```
let image: UIImage!
switch level {
    case 1:
        image = UIImage(named: "lvl1.png")
    case 2:
        image = UIImage(named: "lvl2.png")
    case 3:
        image = UIImage(named: "lvl3.png")
    default:
        image = UIImage()
}
avatar.image = image
```

Comment: I think @MoayasAlkouz 's answer is probably safer with the switch case and setting a default image with an empty constructor.

Comment: @enea-dume No need for a `var` here. The switch is complete which means image will always have a value and will never be uninitialized. Using `let` is ok in this case.

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz i have such error: https://c.radikal.ru/c16/1807/6e/2da4d2391c1d.png

Comment: Assign your image to your imageView:  `avatar.image = image`.

Comment: this is notify you that image variable is not used, put 'avatar.image = image' after switch case

Comment: Am I stupid?
https://c.radikal.ru/c19/1807/1c/460e43375df7.png
//
https://a.radikal.ru/a38/1807/8a/b0e6c5dbdcee.png

Comment: @IvanA at the end of switch brackets, look at edited answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
 imgName = "lvl" + String(lavel)

 imageView.image = UIImage(named: imgName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create a method that returns an image, like so:

```
func imageFor(level: Int) -> UIImage? {
  let image = UIImage(named: "lvl\(currentLevel)")
  return image
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var currentLevel = 1
let image = imageFor(level: currentLevel)
```

Comment: You should rather refrain from force-unwrapping the image and accept it could return `nil`—which would be the case if the file name didn’t exist. The function should hence return an optional `UIImage`. This way the code is safer and also validity checking is done already.

Comment: @TomE I'm working under the assumption the OP has a small quantity of images and he knows they're all going to be there, but your point is well taken.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var level = 1 {

    didSet {

        self.imageview.image = UIImage(named: "lvl\(level)")

    }
}
```

when you change the level the imageView will change automatically